# how to insert a row/document into MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb

I want to insert data into MongoDB from my android application. I have seen many examples but they did not helped. I am new to Android so please show me an example that how can I insert a row/document to MongoDB from my Android application. I have the data in the form of `String` that has to be inserted. (given below):

```
String data = String.format("{\"document\"  : {\"date\": \"%s\", \"latitude\": \"%s\", \"longitude\": \"%s\", \"name\": \"%s\"}, \"safe\" : true}", "24/6/1995", "33.642550", "72.990790", "Testing SL");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a remote mobile backend to use MongoDB.
It could be a web server in Node/Java/etc. which will expose your Mongo database through REST API. The Android application will do HTTP GET/POST requests to the server through this API to get the JSON response.

Check this tutorial to create REST API backend in node:
[Mobile Developers – Easily Build a Backend REST API with Node.js](http://www.iosinsight.com/backend-rest-api-nodejs/)

Also read this, on how to connect to your mongo server in android:
[how do i connect an android app to MongoDB on a remote server? how do i parse the JSON response?](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-connect-an-android-app-to-mongodb-on-a-remote-server-how-do-i-parse-the-json-response)